# Parse Python JSON (Oanda V20)

Tags: python, json, parsing

Beginner Python coder here, with a question that seems simple to me, but I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

I am trying to Parse the following JSON to simply retrieve 'time' and 'bids/price'

```
{
"prices": [
    {
        "type": "PRICE",
        "time": "2017-05-26T02:21:25.603280035Z",
        "bids": [
            {
                "price": "1.34939",
                "liquidity": 10000000
            }
        ],
        "asks": [
            {
                "price": "1.34956",
                "liquidity": 10000000
            }
        ],
        "closeoutBid": "1.34939",
        "closeoutAsk": "1.34956",
        "status": "tradeable",
        "tradeable": true,
        "unitsAvailable": {
            "default": {
                "long": "33",
                "short": "33"
            },
            "openOnly": {
                "long": "33",
                "short": "33"
            },
            "reduceFirst": {
                "long": "33",
                "short": "33"
            },
            "reduceOnly": {
                "long": "0",
                "short": "0"
            }
        },
        "quoteHomeConversionFactors": {
            "positiveUnits": "1.00000000",
            "negativeUnits": "1.00000000"
        },
        "instrument": "USD_CAD"
    }
]
```

}

I've used multiple variations of code with no result.
Here is my latest :

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import oandapyV20
from oandapyV20 import API
import oandapyV20.endpoints.pricing as pricing
import logging
from datetime import datetime

logging.basicConfig(filename="v20.log", level=logging.INFO, format='%
(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s : %(message)s',)

accountID = 
access_token = 
api = API(access_token = access_token, environment = "live")

params = {"instruments": "USD_CAD"}

r= pricing.PricingInfo(accountID=accountID,params=params)
rv = api.request(r)
json_str = json.dumps(rv, indent=4)
new_json_str = json_str(["prices"])
print(new_json_str)
```

I receive the following error : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the JSON in your question the result of printing json_str(["prices"])?

Comment: No, it's the result of (json_str = json.dumps(rv, indent=4))

Comment: The answer I just posted should work. Let me know if not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it looks like the prices object is a list of objects.

So you have to do

```
jsonVar["prices"][0]["time"]
jsonVar["prices"][0]["bids"]["price"]
```

If there were multiple prices returned you could get all of the information like this:

```
for each priceObject in jsonVar["prices"]:
    print priceObject["time"]
    print priceObject["bids"]["price"]
```

Comment: I've updated code to the following:

    new_json_str = json_str(["prices"][0]["time"])

and receive the following error message : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Looks like the variable is a string - try json.loads(jsonVar) and then performing the steps above.

Comment: when I try json.loads, i receive the following error : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

after printing type(rv), i get the following output : <class 'dict'>

Comment: I followed your recommendation of using json.loads and I am now receiving an output. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps` takes a python object and serializes it as a string in valid json format (ie. it's not an object that can be worked with anymore, it's a string). Seeing what you are doing currently in the code, it looks like `rv` is already a python object in the structure given in your first code snippet?

If `rv` is a python object, then you can simply use that directly to obtain values, without every worrying about json. For example: `rv['prices'][0]['time']` to retrieve the time given your structure.

However, if the api is returning a string formatted as json, then `rv` will be a string and must be parsed as json first. Example:

```
json_data = json.loads(rv)
time = json_data['prices'][0]['time']
```

To help with debugging, try printing `type(rv)` to see whether it's a string or a python dictionary.

Comment: Updating to 'json.loads(rv), the following error message is produced : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

After printing type(rv), i get the following output : <class 'dict'>

Comment: That's because the `rv` variable is _already_ the object you are wanting. In that case, don't even try using the `json` library - you don't need it. Work directly with the `rv` dictionary object. You should be able to access parts of the dictionary directly eg. `rv['prices']` etc. I suggest you do some reading up on python dictionaries. Also read what the error messages are saying - they are helpful.